# Style.Triggers, DataTrigger проблемы при переезде из WPF, how to

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

В WPF юзал такой код:

```
 <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{interop:TypeName Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding CellStatus, Converter={StaticResource CellViewStateConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model1:CellState.NormalCell}}">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NormalCellTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding CellStatus, Converter={StaticResource CellViewStateConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model1:CellState.NulledCell}}">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NulledCellTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding CellStatus, Converter={StaticResource CellViewStateConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model1:CellState.CurrentCell}}">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CurrentCellTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding CellStatus, Converter={StaticResource CellViewStateConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model1:CellState.PossibleCell}}">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource PossibleCellTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding CellStatus, Converter={StaticResource CellViewStateConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model1:CellState.DeleteCell}}">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DeleteCellTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

При переносе в `UWP` он превратился в тыкву. Нагуглил пару костылей, но как-то мне они не понравились и вообще у нас с ними отношения не сложились.

Comment: В UWP нет Style.Triggers, вместо них (отчасти) VisualStates. Что требуется-то в итоге?

Comment: Будет хорошо, если вы хотя бы кините ссылку информация по которой позволит востановить функционал, все что мне попадается сильно фрагментарно, и мне не удалось заставить это заработать.

Comment: Ссылки такой, к сожалению, не имею. Попробуйте добавить в шаблон кнопки нужные Behaviors, это должно помочь. https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki

Comment: Я уже пробовал, там можно толькоцвет поменять, и прочие свойства, а шаблон нет, ну либо я не нашел как это сделать, в сэмплах там тоже нет ничего.

Comment: Какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: В зависимости от содержимого (например есть класс `Cell` а в нем поле `CellStatusEnum CellStatus`), подменялся стиль (или шаблон).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding CellStatus, Converter={StaticResource CellViewStateConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model1:CellState.NormalCell}}" Value="True">
        <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="ItemTemplate" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=myButt}" Value="{StaticResource NormalCellTemplate}"/>
    </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
    <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding CellStatus, Converter={StaticResource CellViewStateConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model1:CellState.NulledCell}}" Value="True">
        <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="ItemTemplate" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=myButt}" Value="{StaticResource NulledCellTemplate}"/>
    </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

 <Button x:Name="myButt" />
```